# Simple Backbone.js fiddle - Am I on the right track?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've been learning about Backbone.js and I'm attempting to try and create a simple project that just deals with one component of Backbone - the View - and then transition into making models and collections as I need them.  It seems like tackling the framework in pieces would make it easier to get my head around it.

I figured that a good starting point would be a login screen that transitions to a home page.  Here is a link to a fiddle that I made and I was wondering if those of you who are more experienced in Backbone could take a look and let me know if I'm on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/tVmTM/

I plan on adding more components to this and growing it out as I learn more about the framework, so it would be great to get some feedback on best-practices to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot right off the bat.

Comment: I think this is generally considered a http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, you are on the right track.

I agree it's a good idea to start simple and then progress to more complicated scenarios as you're learning Backbone.

One small tidbit I have is that Backbone will set the scope context for the event handlers that are declared in the **events** property. What that means is that you do not have to include the **login_press** as an argument in **_.bindAll** because Backbone does that for you.

As you progress, be sure to learn more about [its router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router) and how you can use it in this situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks again Paul.  It looks like one could do a whole lot by just using that router.  I'll have to give it a try.